# Teradata Abort any particular session

Tags: teradata

.  I wish to abort a particular session for which I have the session no from Teradata. I have searched in web and came to know that we can pass the ABORT SESSION command through RDBMS console and BTEQ is an RDBMS console. Is there a particular way to do so?

Thanks for the advice,
Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 4):

BTEQ is not a console utility, but you don't need `ABORT SESSION`, there's a SQL interface to the PMon-API, too:

```
SELECT SYSLIB.AbortSessions (-1, '*', sessionid, 'Y', 'Y');
```

Check the "Application Programming Interface" for details.

Comment: Thank you. I have already checked this function. Since I do not have privilege to execute function just wanted to check if there is any other way to do this. If not then I have to go with requesting privilege for your solution.

Comment: It's the easiest way, so ask your DBA for the necessary rights :)

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth, would you please also have a trick to kill all sessions for a given user?

Comment: Ok found it `SELECT AbortSessions (1, 'USERNAME', 0, 'N', 'N');`

Comment: Actually this statement killed all sessions: `SELECT SYSLIB.AbortSessions (-1, 'USERNAME', 0, 'Y', 'Y');`